# Nginx does not serve image ( 403 - forbidden error )

Tags: nginx

I just set up an nginx server. I can visit my webpage ( an "under construction" page ), but although one image is server properly by the server ( named "logo.png" ), another image on the same directory ( I have everything under the root directory of nginx ) is not served and throws a "403 - Forbidden" error ). Below I show you the "http" part of my nginx.conf file.

```
http {

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ***********.com;
    root html;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions about how I might solve this??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably nginx-user does not have rights to read second file. Options:

1) change chmod of that file so it can be read by everyone

2) add nginx-user and file-owner-user to the same group and allow group to read that file

Comment: the directory has 755 permissions.

Comment: Bless you. Totally spaced it and when I looked at the permissions this was it.